# How far do I need to be from the Iron Golem farm for it to work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an iron golem farm that is about 100 blocks away from me and 230ish blocks away from the nearest village but iron golems don't seem to be spawning. Am i too far away from the iron golem farm for it to work?

Also I'm playing on vanilla minecraft 1.13.2

Comment: Just to confirm, there are actual villages in this iron farm, yes? Otherwise of course nothing spawns. Also, we need more information on the farm in general, because without knowing what you did, we can't know what happens.

Comment: Also, are there 3 or more transparent blocks above the spawning area???

Answer (score 1):

From [the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk):

> Chunks near the player are loaded into memory. The range depends on the Render Distance setting. These chunks may have activity (mobs spawning, trees growing, water flowing, dropped items disappearing etc.), while chunks outside of the range are inactive, and are stored on the disk. Chunks will not save again if they were saved in the last 30 seconds.

Chunks that aren't loaded don't change at all until they're loaded. So if you're 230 blocks away from your iron farm, the render distance would have to be at least 15 chunks (230 % 16 rounded up) for the iron farm to work.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out my render distance was 10 chunks thats why they werent spawning. I set it to 16 and it works perfectly!